# Symfony2: how to add label, attr to Entity to show in form (ContactType form, entity ContactMessage)?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

How to add `label, trim, attr => [placeholder => "Field name"]` to Entity to show in form (form ContactMessageType, entity ContactMessage)?
I'm trying to configure form fields and entity fields in one file -> entity class ContactMessage. 
Is that possible? If yes, how?
If no, what to do?

My entity:

```
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 /**
 * php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
 * php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
 *
 * Class ContactMessage
 * @see http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/registration_form.html
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact_messages", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci"})
 */
class ContactMessage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdDateTime = new \DateTime("now");
    }

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true, "length":11})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @var integer
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="sender_name", nullable=false, length=255, options={})
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $senderName;
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="sender_email", nullable=false, length=512, options={"default":""})
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $senderEmail;
/**
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="sender_message", nullable=false, length=4096, options={"default":""})
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $senderMessage;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="sender_phone_number", nullable=false, length=16, options={"default":""})
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $senderPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_date_time", nullable=false,  options={"default": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $createdDateTime;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure understand your problem, but you can add labels and placeholder inside yout FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('senderName', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'    => 'Your label',
            'attr'     => [
                'placeholder' => 'Your placeholder',
            ],
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I know that, i'm trying to do it in entity. with @Assert\... as i wrote as much as possible in one file (entity) and i adding entity to form as data so i do not know if your code do not damage form when i have twice 'senderName' in form, from entity and manually writing in builder

Comment: @Assert is not used for that, and you can't. It's only used for add assertion on your datas.
You need to separate your form From your Entity because maybe in the futur, you'll need several forms for one Entity